# How to move x lines up in vi/vim editor

Tags: vim, vi

<kbd>n</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> moves the cursor to n lines down from the current position.

is there any shortcut to move n lines up?

Comment: you might want to try the _vimtutor_ tutorial to for an introduction to some basic elements of all the magic vim has to offer. To find out how to start it, you can type `:help vimtutor` _<Enter>_ in vim's Normal mode or follow this link: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_01.html#vimtutor

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
<n>k
```

(You can also use `<n>j` to move down, `<n>h` to move left and `<n>l` to move right)

Also: Read `:help motion`.

Comment: If you use the arrow keys, preceding them with a count also works.

Comment: Al's right. It took me a few years to get serious about using h/j/k/l instead of the arrow keys, but I'm so glad I did. The real secret is to use things like 'w', 'b', ')', etc. to move around even faster.